# Edit all the similar files in subdirectories in linux in one shot

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have the directory structure as shown in the image below.
Can there be a script written in linux which basically traverses everything under the sub directories and adds a line of text in the beginning of the file having extension as .txt

there are multiple folders but all have a file having extension .txt

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
find Root -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i '1i\
line to insert
' {} +
```

The `find` command will recurse from the `Root` directory, looking for filenames that match `*.txt`. It will then execute the `sed` command, which inserts a line at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Thanks for the help barmar.
just a follow up, if the data already exists, is there any way to ignore writing to that file.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case `sed -i` switch is not there.

```
for file in `find Root -type f -name "*.txt"`; do sed '1i\
this is the line
' $file > ${file}_new; done
```